# Unable to run pyspark 2.X due to hive metastore connectivity issues

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

When running `pyspark` 1.6.X it comes up just fine.

```
17/02/25 17:35:41 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.13 (default, Dec 17 2016 23:03:43)
SparkContext available as sc, SQLContext available as sqlContext.
>>>
```

But after I reset `SPARK_HOME`, `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` to point to spark 2.x installation, things go south quickly

(a) I have to manually delete a derby `metastore_db` each time.

(b) `pyspark` does not launch: it hangs after printing these unhappy warnings:

```
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
NOTE: SPARK_PREPEND_CLASSES is set, placing locally compiled Spark classes ahead of assembly.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/02/25 17:32:49 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/02/25 17:32:53 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
17/02/25 17:32:53 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
```

I do not need/care for `hive` capabilities: but it may well be they are *required* in case of spark 2.X. What is the simplest working configuration for `hive` to make `pyspark 2.X` happy?

Comment: There warnings are OK, they just say about creating empty metastore. What libraries do you append in `SPARK_PREPEND_CLASSES`? Can you attach thread dump of spark jvm process when pyspark initialization hangs?

Comment: Have you tried the [`enableHiveSupport`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.Builder.enableHiveSupport) function? I had issues with DataFrames when migrating from 1.6 to 2.x, even when I wasn't accessing Hive. Calling that function on the builder solved my problem. (You can also add it to the config.)

Comment: @santon  Please make that an answer: I do have some follow-up question on it but want to start with granting credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [enableHiveSupport](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.Builder.enableHiveSupport) function? I had issues with DataFrames when migrating from 1.6 to 2.x, even when I wasn't accessing Hive. Calling that function on the builder solved my problem. (You can also add it to the config.)

If you're using the pyspark shell to provision your Spark context, to enable hive support you'll need to do so via the config. In your `spark-defaults.conf` try adding `spark.sql.catalogImplementation hive`.

Comment: This is a useful consideration. But how to handle that `pyspark` does not even *launch* ?  It is my understanding you were referring to the `SparkSession.Builder` - but in the case of running in `pyspark-shell` a SparkSession is already created and available .

Comment: So using the pyspark shell loads the default config. I'll modify the answer to show how to enable Hive in the config.